# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, dynamic-sql

I have a mysql dynamic-sql statement and I want to run it using pdo, and I get the following error message:

> Warning: PDOStatement::fetchAll() [pdostatement.fetchall]:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error in C:\xampp\htdocs\tags\cobasql.php on
>   line 29

Here's my php code:

```
<?php 
   $uname = 'root'; //nama username database 
   $pwd = ''; //Password database 
   $dbname = 'eav_latihan'; //nama Database 

   /* Initialisasi database */ 
   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $uname, $pwd); 
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING); 


   $query = "SET @sql = NULL; ". 
            " SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF(a.Name = ''', ". 
            " a.Name, ''', ca.value, NULL)) AS ', a.Name )) INTO @sql ". 
            " FROM cust_attribute ca ". 
            " INNER JOIN attribute a ON ca.idAttribute = a.idAttribute ". 
            " INNER JOIN customer c ON c.idCustomer = ca.idCustomer ". 
            " WHERE a.publish = 'Y'; ". 
            " SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT c.idCustomer, c.namaCustomer, ' ". 
            " ' c.email, c.noTelp, ', @sql, ' FROM cust_attribute ca', ". 
            " ' INNER JOIN attribute a ON ca.idAttribute = a.idAttribute', ". 
            " ' INNER JOIN customer c ON c.idCustomer = ca.idCustomer', ". 
            " ' GROUP BY c.idCustomer'); ". 
            " SELECT @sql; ". 
            " prepare stmt FROM @sql; ". 
            " execute stmt;"; 

   $result_array = array();
   $queryku = $db->query($query);
   $result_array = $queryku->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   echo $result_array;
?>
```

Anyone here can help me or give me a suggest please??

Comment: Please tell me thats not how you're rendering your `$query`... Although good to see you using PDO.

Comment: You do not need to join query elements using `"SELECT"."this"."that"` in a query, when you can achieve using `"SELECT this, that"`.

Comment: what do you mean?? can you fix my query?

Answer (score -1):

It seams like you cant connect!

This line here

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$dbname, $uname, $pwd);
```

Try to remove the $dbname var and type in a right value so your line looks like

```
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $uname, $pwd);
```